# Can a SQLite database be Open, but not Readable?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on Android application and want to ask if it might be possible for a SQLiteDatabase object, which is the object used to interact with the underlying SQLite db, to be Open (as in `returns TRUE` on `db.isOpen()`), but still not be readable?

What scenarios are possible? Locking?

Example:

```
SQLiteAppHelper sqliteHelper = SQLiteAppHelper.getInstance(context);
SQLiteDatabase appDB = sqliteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

Note: The code above is using a class that `extends SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: For SQLlite, I suggest you check your connection string. Depending on your provider, you may get a valid open even though the open failed.

Comment: Are you opening the database as 'writeable' i.e. 
mDB = mDatabase.getWritableDatabase();?

Comment: Also you might want to post your code that you are using to open the database

Comment: What is the specific problem that you have?

Comment: I don't have a specific problem. Yet.
But I would like to check that a local SQLite db is Open and Readable.
The Android platform does not provide that function, like `isOpen()`. There is no `isReadable()`. So I'm asking if a if it's possible for a Android SQLite db, that is Open, is not Readable.